# Related Field got invalid lookup: name

Tags: python, django, search, django-rest-framework, lookup

I am trying to implement Q search on my APIView, but it says invalid lookups name which is strange. I have added the search fields according to the fields of the models.

My view:

```
from django.db.models import Q
class PrdouctSearchAPIView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]   

    # def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        qur = self.request.query_params.get('search')

        item = Product.objects.filter(Q(category__name__icontains=qur)|
                                       Q(brand__name__icontains=qur)|
                                       Q(description__icontains=qur)|
                                       Q(collection__name__icontains=qur)|
                                       Q(variants__name__icontains=qur))
        serializer = ProductSerializer(item,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

My models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    
    merchant = models.ForeignKey(Seller,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=False)
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # is product featured?
    description = RichTextField(blank=True)
    variants = models.ManyToManyField(Variants,related_name='products')

class Category(models.Model):
    #parent = models.ForeignKey('self',related_name='children',on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)  


class Brand(models.Model):
    brand_category = models.ManyToManyField(Category,blank=True,null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)  

class Collection(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
```

My url is :

```
path('api/productsearch',views.PrdouctSearchAPIView.as_view(),name='api-productsearch'),
```

As we can see there are fields "category__name" and such not only "name", but the error says invalid lookup "name".

Comment: As far I can see, product model does not have fields description and variants

Comment: I have added the fields. It was there I just forgot to post @JarnoLahtinen

Comment: Try to remove criteria one by one and. Then we are closer to find out which fails.